# Create Several Excel Worksheets dynamically and at the same time

Tags: c#

I am able to create an Excel Spreadsheet with several Worksheets using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  The problem is that it is taking too long a time to create all the Worksheets with formulae.

Is there a way that I could create these worksheets possibly in separate threads and at the same time so as to cut processing time?

Comment: Use EPPlus instead. No point creating multiple instances of an entire excel app and telling it what to do/save when a lightweight library can create XLSX files directly

Comment: Kindly provide some example how to do that. I am not familiar with EPPlus

Comment: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus - "for support ask on StackOverflow, there's a tutorial in the wiki and a sample app in the codebase"